# No more previews in compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

In Node Editor (Compositing) there are no previews in the "Viewer" and "Composite" nodes. The Backdrop works and the "Render Layers" nodes also show their preview.

I found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/no-previews-showing-in-the-compositor) but this doesn't help.
I can do F12 as much as I like. There are no previews in compositor.

So it looks currently:

[image: So it looks]

I want it to look that way (screenshot from a YouTube video):

[image: Expected]

Is there an option I could have disabled accidentally?

(I am using Blender Render engine, not Cycles.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In the Compositor**

- Select Node First. Toggle Node Preview.

[image]

[image]

- Make sure you click on a Viewer.  It should have a highlight.
- Make sure Backdrop (Show Backdrop) is enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP is talking about the preview thumbnails on the nodes themselves, not the backdrop.

Comment: Backdrop works. My problem (and as I look at your screenshot: yours too ;-)) is that the nodes themselves have no preview. - Check the screenshot I posted from the YouTube video.

Comment: Now my reading skills are like those of Steve Harvey.   I take full responsibility.  Still a Great Night folks.