# Node settings to composite my character within real footage through camera tracking

Tags: node-editor, render-layers, compositing-nodes

I'm following a book on character creation in Blender and I'm currently trying to composite my character within real footage through camera tracking. I'm at a part where I'm trying to set up the character and its shadows in a separate Render Layer and adjust them through Nodes. However, in the book, the two Render Layers have a transparent image showing. They're not showing for me. Also, adjusting things like the RGB curves has no effect. Have I set this up right? Or have I missed something?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not all questions need the file. It is easier to find answers if you post images showing the nodes you are using in the compositor. Use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491). Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to modify your post.

Comment: most likely duplicate of: [transparent rendered object over tracked background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876)

Comment: Nope, I don't have a transparent object. The object appears in the footage fine. It's the Render Layer image that should be showing something and it's blank.

Comment: No pictures for us to show the issue?

Comment: Okay, so I think the issue was, was that I needed to do a test render, and then transparent images appeared. However, the one for the character's shadows don't. I've still yet to add the rest of the nodes from the book, but I'm pretty sure the shadows should be appearing within the image.

Comment: For those more serious about compositing into footage, I’d recommend Paul Chamber’s excellent series http://www.paulchambers3d.com/blog/2017/8/22/adventures-in-scene-referred-space-part-one as well as Sebastian König’s post which tackles similar issues http://blendfx.com/working-with-blender-and-the-arri-alexa/.

Comment: You need to render something by pressing F12 or pressing the render button, so that the compositor has information to work with.  Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6436/1853

Comment: I’ve set up all the nodes now from the book, but the shadows won’t show. I’ve rendered the scene with F12, but only the character shows. I have the character on one Render Layer and the plane he walks on on another. I’m working in Cycles, by the way.